# Setting total number of Marklogic forests for a database in ml-gradle

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10, ml-gradle

I'm currently working on configuring the resources like databases and app servers for an application using ml-gradle.These configurations would be deployed to ML10 environment.

I have a content database and there are nine hosts in the environment. I have set the ml-gradle property `mlContentForestsPerHost=1` ,so it is creating 9 forests in total for the content database.

But I need only 5 forests in total for my content database to be created.

Is there a way to do it via any ml-gradle property or this can be achieved using json forest config only?

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Creating-forests#properties-driven - specifically mlDatabaseHosts or possibly mlDatabaseGroups.

Comment: Yes,I have seen the mlDatabaseHosts property usage but I have saliman properties with my ml- gradle to use it in different environments(dev, test, UAT, and prod).So,I couldn't set a particular environment hosts for this property in gradle.properties. Is it possible that I could have a variable for the list of hosts for each environment in gradle-{env}. properties and then use that variable in gradle.properties file for mlDatabaseHosts property?

Comment: You can put a different value for mlDatabaseHosts in each gradle-(env).properties file, and you can also omit it from gradle.properties. That way, when deploying locally - i.e. when not specifying an environment name - you'll get a forest on each host, which is typically just one host when working locally.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this and let you know. What do you mean by deploying locally?

Comment: Deploying locally = not specifying an environment name, so the Gradle properties plugin will use whatever's in gradle.properties and gradle-local.properties